# Why is SIGHUP ignored by daemon(3) only in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, signals, posix, daemon, nohup

As part of the [`systemd` `tmux` `daemon()` discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4ln242/systemd_developer_asks_tmux_and_other_programs_to/), I've noticed that it's only the [FreeBSD version of `daemon()` `libc` library call](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/lib/libc/gen/daemon.c#daemon) that ignores [`SIGHUP`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/sys/signal.h#SIGHUP) [`sigaction(2)`](http://mdoc.su/f/sigaction.2), but not [OpenBSD](http://openbsd.su/src/lib/libc/gen/daemon.c#daemon) or glibc/misc/daemon.c.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

I traced it down to https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=122442 and https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25462.

There appear to be a few corner cases where [`SIGHUP`](http://openbsd.su/src/sys/sys/signal.h#SIGHUP) [`signal`](http://mdoc.su/f/signal.3) gets delivered when the [`daemon()`](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/lib/libc/gen/daemon.c#daemon) library call does a [`fork(2)`](http://mdoc.su/f/fork.2) followed by an [`_exit(2)`](http://mdoc.su/f/_exit.2) of the parent, which would make [`hup`](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sys/fs/procfs/procfs_ctl.c#signames) be delivered (as per [`_exit(2)`](http://mdoc.su/f/_exit.2)) and will terminate the child process if the parent from which it is executed is already the session leader as described in [`setsid(2)`](http://mdoc.su/f/setsid.2).

To avoid the above unintended termination of the child in these limited circumstances when the caller is the session leader (full list when that is the case is in Bugzilla above), the `SIGHUP` is temporarily ignored.